# How to combine the value of multiple hashes within an array by the same key

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes like so:

```
[{"apple"=>5}, {"banana"=>4}, {"orange"=>6}, {"apple"=>4}, {"orange"=>2}]
```

How I do get to:

```
[{"apple"=>9}, {"banana"=>4}, {"orange"=>8}]
```

Comment: Show us what you have got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also:

```
cache = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { k => 0 } }
aoh.flat_map(&:to_a)
   .each_with_object(cache) { |(k,v),h| h[k][k] += v }
   .values
```

Or in more pieces to be a little clearer:

```
cache   = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { k => 0 } }
sum     = -> ((k, v), h) { h[k][k] += v }
summary = aoh.flat_map(&:to_a)
             .each_with_object(cache, &sum)
             .values
```

The somewhat odd looking `cache` Hash does two things at once:

1. Keeps track of which keys have been seen so far in its keys.
2. Keeps track of the final results we want in its values.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. In "real life" I'd probably use the "more pieces" version wrapped in a nicely named method. I'm quite fond of the "use a lambda instead of a block so that it can have a name" technique.

Comment: I've noticed.  "...And on his mind he had a lambda, E-I-E-I-O. With a `call`, `call` here, and a `[]`, `[]` there, here a `()`, there a `yield`, everywhere a `call`, `call`...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think of creating a new hash.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, as you will soon see. Here's one:

```
arr = [{"apple"=>5}, {"banana"=>4}, {"orange"=>6}, {"apple"=>4}, {"orange"=>2}]

arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
   .group_by(&:first)
   .map { |k,a| { k=>(a.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,v)| tot+v }) } } 
  #=> [{"apple"=>9}, {"banana"=>4}, {"orange"=>8}]
```

The steps:

```
a = arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [["apple",5], ["banana",4], ["orange",6], ["apple",4], ["orange",2]] 
b = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"apple"=>[["apple", 5], ["apple", 4]],
  #   "banana"=>[["banana", 4]],
  #   "orange"=>[["orange", 6], ["orange", 2]]} 
b.map { |k,a| { k=>(a.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,v)| tot+v }) } }
  #=> [{"apple"=>9}, {"banana"=>4}, {"orange"=>8}]
```

Let's take a closer look at `b.map`:

```
enum = b.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: {
  #     "apple"=>[["apple", 5], ["apple", 4]],
  #     "banana"=>[["banana", 4]],
  #     "orange"=>[["orange", 6], ["orange", 2]]
  #   }:map>
```

The first element of `enum` is passed (by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which in turn calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)) to the block and assigned to the block variables. We can simulate that using [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
 k,a = enum.next
   #=> ["apple", [["apple", 5], ["apple", 4]]]
 k #=> "apple"
 a #=> [["apple", 5], ["apple", 4]]
```

To calculate:

```
 c = a.reduce(0) { |tot,(_,v)| tot+v }
   #=> 9
```

the first element of `a` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned:

```
 tot, (_,v) = 0, ["apple", 5]
     #=> [0, ["apple", 5]] 
 tot #=> 0
 v   #=> 5
```

We then compute:

```
 tot + 5
   #=> 0+5 => 5
```

which is returned to `reduce` to become the updated value of `tot`. The second value of `a` is passed in:

```
 tot, (_,v) = 5, ["apple", 4]
 tot #=> 5
 v   #=> 4
```

and we calculate and return:

```
 tot+4
   # 5+4 => 9
```

so:

```
 { k=>tot }
   #=> { "apple"=>9 }
```

is the mapped value of the first element of `a`. The remaining mapped values are computed similarly.